# DateTime to String error

Tags: c#

Hello I'm trying to convert a DateTime to String but get an error.

```
    public DateTime? ArkivDate { get; set; }



   private string GetPdfPath()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(ROOT + person.PersonalIdentityNumber) == false) { Directory.CreateDirectory(ROOT + person.PersonalIdentityNumber); }
            string ret = ROOT + person.PersonalIdentityNumber + "\\" + person.ItemNumber + "-" + person.PersonalIdentityNumber + "-" + person.CertificateTypeCode + "-" + person.IssuingDate.Value.ToString() + ".pdf";
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to use `ret` as a filename

The error says the format is wrong.

The error message:

> The entered path format is not supported

**UPDATE:**

So apperently this **DOES** work:

[image]

But this does **NOT**

[image]

Comment: **Where** does the error occur? Since the error is about some sort of "format", are you trying to parse a date or write a file with invalid characters in the filename?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - at the moment, all the answers are really guesses, and don't fit in with the error you're talking about. Basically, we don't have *nearly* enough information to help you yet.

Comment: does `person.ArkivDate` have a value?

Comment: @cubrr The error occurs when trying to convert the ArkivDate to string. I updated my question.

Comment: @user1666620 Yes it does.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact error message?

Comment: @Simon.S what is the value of `person.ArkivDate`?

Comment: @user1666620 Well it's a date.. Year, month and day

Comment: An error of "The entered path format is not supported" would not come from the code you've shown. It's likely to come from using the string returned by it as a filename. Hint: look at the filename you've got, and ask yourself whether it looks valid. Does it contain colons, for example?

Comment: @cubrr Updated my question with the error message.

Comment: @Simon.S I don't think `/` are valid in filenames

Comment: The error seems to me is because after this code you are showing us, you try to do something with that pdf filename and it probably has forbidden characters, as `/` or something like that

Comment: `<<<The error happens here`  That wasn't actually true, was it?

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right. I was trying to use the string returned as a filename. But why shouldn't it work. I only get the error when including a date into that name. Take a look at my updated code and tell me if something is off. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Well, we don't know what filename you've got, which doesn't help - it will depend on your locale. But it's very likely that the returned value will include a colon. Try creating a file which includes a colon...

Comment: Examine the value of ret in the debugger.  You should use the Path.Combine function to create proper file paths.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and hovering over 'ret' to see what it is? It is very likely it contains an illegal character. Debugging should very quickly confirm that for you. A backslash for example wouldn't be allowed, which it looks like you're trying to add between person.PersonalIdentityNumber + "\\" + person.ItemNumber.

Comment: So the problem is `IssuingDate` i guess. Try `IssuingDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: @JonSkeet Please check my updated question. I'm comparing both value of the `ret` just so you can see that there are really nothing that shouldn't be working...

Comment: @Simon.S the problem is the time. `:` is not allowed in a path name

Comment: It would have been *much* easier to read that if you'd included the strings *as text* in your question. But for the third time: your broken filename contains colons. **Colons are not valid in Windows filenames.**

Comment: @sr28: A backslash is fine in a filename, just as a directory separator. A colon is *not* valid...

Comment: Ohh sorry I must have missed that one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a nullable DateTime you have to use the Value:

```
string ret = person.ArkivDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".pdf";
```

Please make sure your ArkivDate is initialised with a valid date also. We are explicitly casting the string to a 'dd-MM-yyyy' format as dates with '/' will not work as a filename.

Comment: Your example works even without `.Value`, so that is not the issue here.

Comment: Tried it, still the same error.

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Comment: Note that `yyyy-MM-dd` would be a much cleaner format, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

When you format a datetime as the file name you must make sure it does not contain a forward slash "/" since windows does not allow / in the file because it will clash as the path. so make sure to format the dateTime as  **person.ArkivDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")**

Comment: Colons are also a problem

Answer (score 0):

ArkivDate is property of type Nullable, so you should check if it has value first.

```
if (person.ArkivDate.HasValue)
    return person.ArkivDate.Value.ToString() + ".pdf";
return null;
```